# List versus ArrayList as reference type?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, interface

Ok so I know that `Set`, `List` and `Map` are interfaces but what makes the first line of code any better than the second line?

```
List myArr = new ArrayList();
ArrayList myArr = new ArrayList();
```

Comment: Second line is better because ArrayList type provides more functionality in addition to List. However the List type is better when you do code that does not depend on List implementation. Please cover my [Internal life of ArrayList](http://volodial.blogspot.com/2013/07/internal-life-of-arraylist-in-java.html) to know it deeper.

Comment: @VolodymyrLevytskyi page does not exist, first is good too

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you use the first form, you are saying all you are ever going to use is the functionality of the `List` interface - nothing else, especially nothing extra added by any implementation of it. This means you can easily change the implementation used (e.g. just substitute `LinkedList` for `ArrayList` in the instantiation), and not worry about it breaking the rest of the code because you might have used something specific to `ArrayList`.

Comment: I think the case can be made more compelling when you mention wrapping your ArrayList in a Collections.checkedList() for debugging. When you mention LinkedList, people say "why would I ever use LinkedList?".

Comment: @ILMTitan: Agreed. That is a far more common scenario than having to switch to `LinkedList`. But `LinkedList` is useful too, I have had to switch to using them whenever I needed to make lots of adds/removes  to the beginning. The main point here is to separate the implementation and the interface so that the implementation can change without having to make lots of changes to the rest of the code.

Answer (score 15):

A useful general principle about types in programming (sometime referred to as the [robustness principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle)) is as follows:

- Be liberal about what you accept
- Be conservative about what you emit

List is more liberal than ArrayList, since List can be any kind of List implementation e.g. an ArrayList, a LinkedList or FrancosSpecialList. Hence it is a good idea to be liberal and accept any kind of list since you may want to change the implementation later.

The main reason to use ArrayList explicitly as a type (your second case) is if you need to use methods that are specific to ArrayList that are not available through the List interface. In this case a generic List won't work (unless you want to do lots of ugly and confusing casting), so you might as well be explicit and use an ArrayList directly. This has the added bonus of hinting to a reader that specific features of ArrayList are needed.

Answer (score 7):

As you can see from the source of `ArrayList` [here](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/ArrayList.java.html), most of the methods implemented are annotated as `@override` because all of them that are defined through `List` interface so, if you are gonna use just basic functionalities (that is what you are gonna do most of the time) the difference won't be any practical one.

The difference will come if someday you will think that the features of the `ArrayList` are not suitable anymore for your kind of problem and you will need something different (a `LinkedList` for example). If you declared everything as `List` but instantiated as `ArrayList` you will easily switch to new implementation by changing the instantiations to `new LinkedList()` while in other case you will have to change also all variable declarations.

Using `List list = new ArrayList()` is more OOP style since you declare that you don't care about the specific implementation of the list, and that you want to discard the static information about the type since you will rely on the interface provided by this kind of collection abstracting from its implementation.