# OOP: Difference between ArrayList al = new ArrayList() and List al = new ArrayList()?

Tags: java, collections

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List versus ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062982/list-versus-arraylist)

Difference between

```
ArrayList al = new ArrayList()
```

and

```
List al = new ArrayList() ?
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

None, from a creation perspective. Both create an instance of `ArrayList`.

The difference is that, in you second example, `al` allows access to all methods implemented on the `List` interface while, in the first example, `al` allows access to all (accessible) methods and fields of the `ArrayList` class.

A practical rule of thumb: use the second pattern. If you need some extra goodies from the `ArrayList` implementation, then you can always cast:

```
 List list = new ArrayList();
 // do some adds/removes/... on the list
 ((ArrayList) list).trimToSize();
```

Comment: Thnk u abdreas D but 1 thing what is the rule of thumb?

Comment: @Hari kanna - Use an interface type, if available, so `List` or even `Collection`. That's what I do in 99.5% of all cases.

Answer (score 7):

Its called programming to interface. Suppose, you need to return this `list` from your method. So the calling code can have that into a `List` variable.

```
public ArrayList getList() {
   ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    // do something with the list here
   return list;
}
```

And this,

```
public List getList() {
   List list = new ArrayList();
    // do something with the list here
   return list;
}
```

Now for the latter method calling code can have the returned list in `List` type variable. And you can easily decide later, for some reason, something like this,

```
public List getList() {
   List list = new LinkedList();
    // do something with the list here
   return list;
}
```

No change in calling code, whereas with the former you need to change the return type, that would eventually screw up the calling code as well.

Answer (score 7):

Paraphrasing [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348199/java-hashmap-vs-map-objects/1348228#1348228) to [this very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348199/java-hashmap-vs-map-objects) about `Map` vs. `HashMap`:

There is no difference between the objects. There is a difference in the *interface* you have to the object. In the first case, the interface is `ArrayList`, whereas in the second it's `List`. The underlying object, though, is the same.

The advantage to using `List` is that you can change the underlying object to be a different kind of list without breaking your contract with any code that's using it. If you declare it as `ArrayList`, you have to change your contract if you want to change the underlying implementation.