# Adding to HashMap gives NPI

Tags: java, static, nullpointerexception, hashmap

In my main class that is run on startup, it tries to put some data into a HashMap. But it's saying that HashMap is null, and that it can't add the data.

```
public class COD extends JavaPlugin{

    public void loadConfig(){
        Settings.gunradius.put("Famas", getConfig().getInt("guns.Famas"));
    }
}

public class Settings {
    static HashMap<String, Integer> gunradius;
}
```

It won't put the data into the HashMap. I suspect it has something to do with the methods being static, but I don't really know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize `HashMap` before using it. Default value internalized to object is `null`

```
static final Map<String, Integer> gunradius = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
 static HashMap<String, Integer> gunradius;
```

to

```
 static HashMap<String, Integer> gunradius= new HashMap<String, Integer();
```

otherwise your `gunradius` will be pointing to `null`.

Any operation on `null` reference results in `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Also, teach OP that it would be better to program to interfaces, not to the implementation classes: [When should I use an interface vs an implementation when declaring a new object?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4991516/1065197).