# Creating objects from classes that implement interfaces in Java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why should the interface for a Java class be prefered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147468/why-should-the-interface-for-a-java-class-be-prefered)

In Java, is there a difference between these two lines? If so, what is it, and when should I use either one?  Is there a preferred convention?

Note that ArrayList implements List.

```
List<String> bunchOfStrings = new ArrayList<String>();

ArrayList<String> bunchOfStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: and specific to the example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062982/list-versus-arraylist

Comment: @Kublai, if you click on my link, you'll see it's specific to this question as well. ;)

Comment: @Kirk - yeah I meant in terms of the accepted answer. Just adding info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both case you are instantiating an ArrayList. The difference is that in the first case you are referring it as a List (the interface that ArrayList implements ), so you don't have access to specific method of ArrayList class, but only interfaces method.

use thi first:

```
List<String> bunchOfStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
```

This way you can switch different List implementation (ArrayList, Vector):

```
public class AClass(){
   List<String> bunchOfStrings;

   public List<String> getList(){
        bunchOfStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
        //or you can switch to : bunchOfStrings = new Vector<String>();
        return bunchOfString;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> ***In Java, is there a difference between these two lines?***

Yes, there is a slight difference, and the `List<String>` variant is preferred.

> ***Is there a preferred convention?***

The convention says that you should *"program against interfaces"*. The reason is that it becomes much easier to swap the actual implementation (in this case from `ArrayList` to say `LinkedList`).

Answer (score 1):

You should use the most generic type possible.  So in this case that's `List`.  The only time you would use a more specific type is if that type had methods defined on it that the more generic type does not.

The reason is that if a method accepts a type, like `List`, the user of the method can provide any type of List they want.  If a method only accepts an ArrayList, the user can't use any other type of List.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare `bunchOfStrings` as a `List`, you can't call any of the `ArrayList` methods (without casting), even though it is pointing to an `ArrayList` object -- you can only call methods that are declared in the `List` class.

For this reason, you might think that it's better to always declare your variable type to be as specific as possible, but declaring it as a `List` is generally preferable because it allows you to change the underlying implementation of your `List` without having to change anything else in your code.  You can easily modify your code as follows without breaking anything else in your code:

```
List<String> bunchOfStrings = new LinkedList<String>();
```

As a rule of thumb, only ever declare the type of your variable to be a specific subclass if you...

1. ...need access to methods that are only available in the subclass.
2. ...need to pass the object instance to a method that only accepts objects of that subclass.

Answer (score 0):

This is called [Polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29).  It is very useful and has no real drawbacks.

**Pros:**

You can send this instance variable to any method that wants a "List" object.

Using List in a method declaration, you are opening up the method to anything that is a sub-type of List, instead of just of type ArrayList.

**Cons:**

You would have to cast your variable to an ArrayList to access or set any features/methods/fields that are in ArrayList (but not in List). But those things are still available.