# What are the List or ArrayList declaration differences in Java?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I am new to Java.
I want to know the difference between:

```
List< String > list = new ArrayList<>();
```

and

```
ArrayList< String > list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and

```
ArrayList< String > list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first one is only valid since Java 7, and is the equivalent of

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

It's just less verbose.

Same for the third one, which is equivalent to

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and thus strictly equivalent to the second one.

You should prefer the first one, for the reasons mentioned in the answers to the following question: [List versus ArrayList as reference type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062982/list-versus-arraylist)

Answer (score 4):

The three are somewhat equivalent:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

In the above, you're declaring a variable that implements the `List` interface which will contain `String` elements, and instantiate it with  the concrete class `ArrayList`. Also, you're using Java 7's new diamond syntax, son you don't have to write again `String` between the `<>`.

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

In the above, you're declaring a variable of the concrete class `ArrayList` which will contain `String` elements, and instantiate it with  the concrete class `ArrayList` using the "traditional" syntax which mandates that you specify the `String` type between the `<>`.

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

In the above, you're declaring a variable of the concrete class `ArrayList` which will contain `String` elements, and instantiate it with  the concrete class `ArrayList`. Also, you're using Java 7's new diamond syntax, son you don't have to write again `String` between the `<>`.

Be aware that the diamond syntax (`<>`) will only work in Java 7 and above, for previous versions of Java you're stuck with using the traditional syntax (`<the-type>`) for instantiating generics.

The last two forms are completely equivalent; the first form is a bit different since you're specifying that the `list` variable is of type `List` and not of type `ArrayList` - and that's the preferred form, since good object-oriented practices dictate that you should [program to an 'interface', not an 'implementation'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns#Introduction.2C_Chapter_1).

Answer (score 2):

There are two points to remark here:

1.The new Java 7 diamond operator allows you to instantiate a generic class without specifying the type parameter on both sides. So these two are equivalent:

> ```
> ArrayList< String > list = new ArrayList<String>();
> ArrayList< String > list = new ArrayList<>();
> ```

2.The more important point is the difference between the first two instantiations. The second one is clear:

```
ArrayList< String > list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

In the first one:

```
List< String > list = new ArrayList<>();
```

you are using the fact that `ArrayList` is a subtype of `List` and therefore the assignment is valid. However, on the new `list` object you only have the subset of methods that are included in `List` (because your object is declared as `List` after all), but with the implementations present in `ArrayList`. This is called polymorphism in object-oriented programming and allows you to use a subtype of a class instead of the parent, where the parent is expected, in order to provide various different functionalities.