# Why assign a new ArrayList to a List variable?

Tags: java

I am new to java and when I go through the code of many examples on net I see people declaring the variable for an `ArrayList` as simply `List` in almost all the cases.

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

I don't understand if there is some specific advantage of doing this. Why can't it be an `ArrayList` itself, like so:

```
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: You will need to change your language: This does not involve casting in the least. Nowhere do you see a cast, `(List)` being used.

Comment: I think it's covered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062982/list-versus-arraylist , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852831/why-use-list-list-new-arraylist-instead-of-arraylist-list-new-arraylist , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147468/why-should-the-interface-for-a-java-class-be-prefered :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's called [programming to an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/384067/758280). It allows you to substitute that `ArrayList` for a `LinkedList` if somewhere down the line you decide that a `LinkedList` would be more appropriate.

Comment: Though, the first sentence is OK, ... _It allows you to substitute that ArrayList for a LinkedList if somewhere down the line you decide that a LinkedList would be more appropriate._ does not sound right

Comment: @OpDeCirkel What sounds wrong with it? That is one of the advantages of programming to an interface.

Answer (score 4):

Because if you decide to change it later it's easier:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> myList = new LinkedList<String>();
```

It's more important in method signatures, when changing what you return can force everyone using your function to change their code.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a cast but rather you are using the interface as the declared type of the variable. The reason for doing this is that you can switch which implementation of List you are using. If users of the list only depend on the List interface,  they won't be affected if you using another list type, such as LinkedList.

Comment: I guess, instead of saying _interface as the declared type_, you want to say _interface as the declared type of a variable_.

Answer (score 2):

List is an interface so it can store referance to all classes extending from List Interface.If you used following statment then after some programing steps you can also store other Objects(extending from List) referance.

```
 List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
 ...
 myList =new LinkedList<String>();
```

The main advantage comes with this is code maintenance. For instance, if someone comes and wants to use a LinkedList instead of the ArrayList, you only need to change one line rather than zillions throughout the code. It makes your code a little more flexible.

The whole concept of polymorphism in java relies on java's ability to use interface/base class reference to reference to sub class objects.

Also, programming to an interface rather than to the actual implementation is always seen as a best practice. This would allow the developer to replace one implementation with other/better implementation easily when required.

Answer (score 1):

Java is strongly typed object-oriented language. ....
Let's go through an example: Suppose that you are writing a sort function `sort(ArrayList<> list)`. If the function declared in that way, java wont allow you to sort anything else with that function than `ArrayList`. Better approach would be to define an *abstraction*  (as in your question is) `List`. In that abstraction you declare methods. that all *implementations* must implement-define (ie ArrayList). Now your `sort` function can be declared as `sort(List<> list)` and you can sort with it anything that implements `List` (and follows the contract of the `List` methods).
In this way you can *reuse* code that you wrote for all your *implementations* as long as they obey the contract of the *abstraction*. In Java you achieve this using *interfaces* as abstractions and *classes* as implementations. There are other advantages too, but you have read some book about Object-oriented programming if you want to understand them better.

Answer (score 0):

1) `List` is an interface, the implementation class is `ArrayList` 
 2)  `List` interface extends `Collection`.