# Why do some people use the List base class to instantiate a new ArrayList?

Tags: java

I keep coming across code where people instantiate a new ArrayList and assign it to the List interface, like this:

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
```

What is the reasoning behind this approach?

Comment: so you can change your mind about `ArrayString` without having to rewrite the code.

Comment: It is not only used by "*some people*". It is a must.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why assign a new ArrayList to a List variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007459/why-assign-a-new-arraylist-to-a-list-variable)

Answer (score 19):

To decouple your code from a specific implementation of the interface.

This also helps you to move to another implementation of the `List` interface in the future.

For example -

You have `List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();` later on you decide that you should have used some other implementation of the `List` interface, say `LinkedList` so you would just change it to `List<String> names = new LinkedList<String>();` and nothing breaks.

Comment: So ArrayList<String> could be casted into another implementation of List if required later?

Comment: It could be *replaced* with another implementation of List.

Comment: `Vector` is a legacy, obsolete, ugly, hateful class that one shouldn't use anymore.

Comment: :) Even I do not like it. But thats the closest to ArrayList in terms of its properties.

Comment: It's not only about being able to switch implementations.  It makes your code more generic, flexible, and reusable.  For example, you can write a utility method which operates on an object of type List, and this method will work for *all* valid list implementations.  This is extremely important in library code, but the same principle applies to application code.

Comment: @JimN - You are right. It allows encapsulation too. One can keep adding the benefits of using the interface instead of the real implementation.

Answer (score 4):

> Programming to an interface, not an implementation

It's a [design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) from Gang of Four (GoF). 
Why is that?

You guide by abstract contract instead of concrete implementation.

```
public class MyClass {

    private List myList ;

    public setMyList(List list){
        myList=list;
    }

}
```

what about instead of `ArrayList` implementation you want `LinkedList` implementation? 
 in that way you only has to inject that property with the setter.

Abstraction is the key, you don't know nothing about implementation only guide by specification.

Read this [What does it mean programming to an interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)

Answer (score 4):

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
```

With that you write code against the interface `List`, which makes it easy to switch the implementation in the future if you have to.

In that case the following will suffice -

```
List<String> names = new //some other implementation of List
```

Now if you do something as follows -

```
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
```

You will code against the implementation `ArrayList` itself. And your code is tied to that specific implementation. In case if you have to switch the implementation then it will require a lot of code changes.

Check the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) to discover some of the standard implemenation provided by Java 6.

Answer (score 4):

Such code doesn't *use* the `List` class, it *declares* the variable as being of type `List`. This is called [abstraction](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_%28computer_science%29)

`List` is an *interface*, which defines what methods the actual class has, without specifying *which* actual class is used.

Although not a big deal here, this practice can be very important, even essential in more complexes situations. It's good practice to always follow this pattern.