# Reason for - List list = new ArrayList();

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have seen code like this many times:

`List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();`

Why do people take the parent of `ArrayList` (and other classes) instead of the type of the generated object?

Does that take less performance? Or why should someone do this?

Comment: What is it with the fixation on "performance"? 90% of the time, that's about the *least important* aspect of writing code!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface

Comment: You can also take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17459553/why-do-some-people-use-the-list-base-class-to-instantiate-a-new-arraylist

Comment: @JoachimSauer Perhaps the easiest thing would be if we told newbees that this greatly improves performance, like in "Everybody knows that ..."

Comment: If I can't see the reason for a thing in a programm, for what else should I ask? I wouldn't say that taking the parent-reference gives you a more "readable" code. :)
But now I have the answer, thanks to all.

Comment: @TrudleR: it communicates intent: `List x = new ArrayList()` means that you don't really need any special features of `ArrayList`, you "promise" to "only" use the features exposed by the `List` interface. Taking it further would be `Collection x = new ArrayList()` or even `Iterable x = new ArrayList()`.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

When someone writes code like this, he/she is trying to follow a basic OO design principle which says -

> Program to an interface, not to a concrete implementation

I have explained this principle in [one of my blog posts](http://sayemdb.wordpress.com/2011/05/17/an-intro-to-design-pattern-2/). Look in the `Class Inheritance VS Interface Inheritance` section.

To summarize the post, when you use a reference of a parent type to refer to an instance of a sub-type, you get a lot of flexibility. For example, if you ever need to change your sub-type implementation in the future, you will be able to do that easily, without changing much of your code.

Consider the following method -

```
public void DoSomeStuff(Super s) {
    s.someMethod();
}
```

and a call to this method -

```
DoSomeStuff(new Sub());
```

now, if you ever need to change the logic inside `someMethod`, you can easily do it by declaring a new subtype of `Super`, say `NewSubType`, and changing the logic inside that implementation. In this way, you will never have to touch other existing code which utilizes that method. You will still be able to use your `DoSomeStuff` method in the following way -

```
DoSomeStuff(new NewSubType());
```

Had you declared the parameter of `DoSomeStuff` to be of `Sub`, you would then have to change its implementation too -

```
DoSomeStuff(NewSubType s) {
    s.someMethod();
}
```

and it may also chain/bubble to several other places.

In terms of your collection example, this lets you change the list implementation that a variable is pointing to without much hassle. You can easily use a `LinkedList` in place of an `ArrayList`.

Comment: "Program to an interface, not to a concrete implementation" is a good advice. However, it's not really an argument to do `List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();` because a) this code is still tied to ArrayList due to the constructor and b) it's more about API design and not the private implementation. It's one of the java things you learn from the beginning which is not really justified. Often the implementation offers some niceties which you will never see if you insist on using the interface. Answer is still good, of course. (+1)

Comment: BUT, his argument still stands. You can swap out functionality by changing the argument. This supports several nice code features, such as dependency injection, loose coupling and substitutability.

Comment: @atamanroman: A consequence of that principle encourages you to refer to the concrete instances in terms of their _interfaces_. This is why I think it's relevant here.

Comment: @Chris: Totally agree with you.

Comment: In the original question, there is no argument. Theres only `List<Foo> l = new ArrayList<Foo>();` If the implementation changes, that line changes. Would'nt be any different if it was `ArrayList<Foo> l = new ArrayList<Foo>();`. The whole situation changed if the list was an external dependency (somehow injected). In this case programming to the interface would make a difference and is highly recommended.

Comment: @atamanroman: As I said, the basic idea was to manipulate an instance with a reference of super type. If only the methods defined in the `List` is sufficient to manipulate that instance, then it will be better to do so. Who knows may be in the future he may decide to make it a property rather than a local variable, and he may also decide to inject a different implementation than an `ArrayList`. Certainly referring by the `List` will give him an advantage here. It's the _practice_ which is of importance here.

Answer (score 13):

When you write:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Then you are sure you'll use only the functionality of the *interface* [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html).
 (`ArrayList` implements `List`, so `List` is more flexibl).
Using this, allows you to change the `ArrayList` to other types in the future (like `LinkedList`..).

Comment: thanks. This is really helpfull

Answer (score 12):

It means you can swap out the type of `list` at any point with anything that implements the `List` interface, as opposed to creating a rigid model that can only use `ArrayList`. For example:

```
private List<String> list;

public SomeConstructor()
{
     // At this point, you can make it any type of object you want.
     list = new ArrayList<String>();
     list = new LinkedList<String>();
     list = new AttributeList<String>();
}
```

This will `abstract` your code that uses the `list` object, away from the details like what exact object type `list` is. All it needs to know is that it has the `add` method etc. This is called [Loose Coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling).

Answer (score 5):

To sort things out:

For more flexibility you initiate interface `List`:

So if you don't need all `ArrayList` use `List` only.

You can write something like: `List<String> = Arrays.asList("aa", "bb","cc")`.

For sure, less functionality can help to performance. As you know If you want to use multithreaded application, use `Vector` instead but it will down your performance.

[image]

Took from [here](http://www.wilsonmar.com/1arrays.htm)

Comment: http://www.wilsonmar.com/1arrays.htm

Comment: @Maxim Shoustin: Good picture! Does this mean, that I should take "AbstractMap" as reference for all the map-collection-objects?

Comment: @TrudleR: no, `AbstractMap` is an implementation detail you should never really care about: You *either* reference the map using the `Map` interface *or* a more specific interface (such as `NavigableMap`). In rare cases you might need the specific implementation type, but `AbstractMap` itself is rarely referenced by anyone except when they extend it.

Answer (score 4):

Because a method doesn't have to know what list-implementation you use.

A Method just needs to know that is is a list.

The Method can still be used.

Always program to an interface, not to a concrete implementation. (In this case List)

Answer (score 3):

Generally it is preferred to work with the Interface class (`List` in this case) so that any List implementation could later be substituted with minimal fuss if requirements change.

Although `ArrayList` possibly supports some methods that are not on the `List` interface, this declaration makes it clear that those extra methods are not relevant in that case.

Answer (score 2):

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

In collection framework `List` is an interface while `ArrayList` is implementation. Main reason you'd do this is to decouple your code from a specific `implementation` of the interface also this will be helpful in case if you wish to move to some other implementation of `List` in the future.