# Is "List list = new ArrayList()" really desirable from "ArrayList list = new ArrayList()"?

Tags: java, oop

For example, [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18329311/reason-for-list-list-new-arraylist) says `List list = new ArrayList()` is desirable because it deals with change easily, you can change to other List e.g. LinkedList.

However, is it really desirable on following case, for example

```
List<MyClass> data = new ArrayList<>();

//... long code

Random rand = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
    MyClass record = data.get(rand.nextInt(data.size()));
    ...//processing
}
```

this code contains too many random accesses. If a successor reads `List<MyClass> data = new ArrayList<>();` and thinks "OK, any List is no problem on this code. I add a bit of insertion processing, change ArrayList to LinkedList". This causes too slow processing when too many random accesses are executed.

Not only List, a declaration by interface is desirable unless implementation methods work in a similar way, isn't it?

---

Edit: change to true random access

Comment: You are thinking too specifically, the idea is to abstract operations. What if you wanted a method that could operate on `Set` **and** `List` of element(s)? Then using `Collection` or writing two methods are your choices. There are trade-offs to most decisions in programming.

Comment: This is not vast problem. When I want to use `ArrayList`, is it appropriate to declare by `List`,  that means "other type of List is also allowed".

Comment: Your example loop is poor organization for precisely this reason; you'd be better off using an `Iterator` and skipping every other element. That said, you can always use `RandomAccessList`, and some JDK algorithms do internally check whether a list is a `RandomAccessList`.

Comment: I fixed example code that needs true random access, this case `Iterator` can't be used. And, if you are correct, `List<MyClass> data = new ArrayList<>();` is incorrect and `RandomAccessList<MyClass> data = new ArrayList<>();` is correct.

Comment: "this code contains too many random accesses" — what do you mean by this?

Answer (score 0):

Your code example runs in exactly the same way whether you use:

```
List<MyClass> data = new ArrayList<>();
```

…or you use:

```
ArrayList<MyClass> data = new ArrayList<>();
```

Referring to an object by its more general interface (or superclass) as seen in the first version does not change any behavior. In both examples above, you are manipulating an array-backed list, an `ArrayList` object.

When choosing a particular implementation of [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html), such as [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedList.html) or [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html), you must consider how the list will likely be used in your code. We have multiple implementations because various programs have various needs. For example, if you program is doing many arbitrary accesses by specific position within the list, use `ArrayList`. If you are doing many edits to insert/delete various elements within the list, then use `LinkedList`. Each kind of `List` has its particular advantages.

The point of referring to the collection by its more general interface rather than the specific concrete class is that other code referring to that list will not break when you decide to change from one kind of list to another. If you come to realize that your code will be doing insertions/deletions in the middle of the list more often than arbitrary access by position, you can change this:

```
List<MyClass> data = new ArrayList<>();
```

…to this:

```
List<MyClass> data = new LinkedList<>();
```

…without breaking any other code referring to `data`.

Of course this assumes the other code is satisfied by the methods available on the interface. If your code requires calls to the methods specific to the `ArrayList` class, then you must refer to the list as a `ArrayList` rather than as a `List`.

The last paragraph of yours is unclear. Your mentions about "too many random accesses" and "too slow processing" are not explained. So edit your Question if your concerns have not been addressed.

---

By the way, be aware of the many useful utility methods in the [`Collections`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html) class. To get random elements from `List`, you could copy the list and then call [`Collections.shuffle`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)) to move the elements into randomly-chosen positions.

```
List< String > names = List.of( "Alice" , "Bob" , "Carol" , "Duke" ) ;
List< String > namesRandom = new LinkedList<>( names ) ;  // Copy the list into a second list to leave the original intact.
Collections.shuffle( namesRandom ) ;  // Move around the element positions within this second list.
```

See this [code run live on IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/m2Ca3T).

```
names = [Alice, Bob, Carol, Duke]
namesRandom = [Bob, Carol, Alice, Duke]
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it depends on whether compatibiliy/abstraction is more important than performance.
If random access is a key feature for the funcionality, I think it is acceptable to constrict input as ArrayList and consumers will have to convert their input to ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

The general principle is that the type of the variable should reflect what it is used for, rather than what the object is "made of" (i.e. its internal implementation details).

In most cases, what matters is that the object can be used as a list, and it doesn't matter that a list is "made of" an array, so the standard advice is to declare a variable of type `List<Foo>` instead of `ArrayList<Foo>`.

---

In your specific case, you want to use the object for fast random access; it still doesn't matter that the object is "made of" an array, since any other list implementation with fast random access would be fine. (For example, the return value of [`Arrays.asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-).) So applying the general principle in your case, the type should reflect the fact that you want to use it for fast random access.

Unfortunately, Java does not have a type like `RandomAccessList<Foo>`. There is a marker interface [`RandomAccess`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/RandomAccess.html) which can be used by classes implementing `List` to denote that they support fast random access, but a variable declared like `RandomAccess fooList = new ArrayList();` is not useful since the marker interface does not have methods like `get`.

So the appropriate thing to do is to declare the variable as type `List<Foo>` and either write a comment saying it should support fast random access (if the list is created locally), or check that `fooList instanceof RandomAccess` and throw an `IllegalArgumentException` otherwise (if the list is supplied from elsewhere).