# Java - having issues with ArrayLists

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

[image]

As you can see I have a StaffMember class and trying to make a list of StaffMember objects, but when I go to get them out of the list I get errors. What could be causing this (Or java lists are different from other languages).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you're not using a generic List *variable*, the compiler has no way of knowing what type of objects the List contains, and so you'll have to cast the object returned by the `get(...)` method to the type you believe it to be.

A better solution is to declare your list variable to be a generic `List<StaffMember>`.

```
public class StaffList {    
    private List<StaffMember> list;
```

Comment: "Program to an 'interface', not an 'implementation'." (Gang of Four 1995:18)

Comment: @TristanCunningham: You can still use a `List` variable and assign it an `ArrayList` object since the `ArrayList` class implements the `List` interface, and in fact this is the preferred way to do it.

Comment: @TristanCunningham While it's a [better practice to use a List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17459553/why-do-some-people-use-the-list-base-class-to-instantiate-a-new-arraylist), you can switch `List<StaffMember>` with `ArrayList<StaffMember>`.

Answer (score 1):

I think your life will be better if you do it this way:

```
public class Staff {
    private List<StaffMember> roster;

    public Staff() {
        this.roster = new ArrayList<StaffMember>();
    }

    // add the rest
}
```