# how to deep copy one arraylist into another

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying some java for first time. I tried creating an arraylist of arraylist and wanted to deep copy one arraylist into another arraylist. When executed the below code I get error:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> arrli = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        System.out.println("Enter the array size: ");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int arr[] = new int[n];
        System.out.println("Enter "+ n + " elements: ");
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        ArrayList<Integer> arrli1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            if(i==0) {
                arrli1.add(arr[i]);
            } else if(arr[i] > arr[i-1]) {
                arrli1.add(arr[i]);
            } else if(arr[i] < arr[i-1]) {
                arrli.add(arrli1.clone());
                arrli1.clear();
                arrli1.add(arr[i]);
            }
            if(i==(n-1)) {
                arrli.add(arrli1);
            }
        }
        int s = arrli.size();
        int inner_size;
        for(int i=0; i<s; i++) {
            inner_size = arrli.get(i).size();
            for(int j=0; j<inner_size; j++){
                System.out.print(arrli.get(i).get(j));
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
/MyClass.java:21: error: no suitable method found for add(Object)
                arrli.add(arrli1.clone());
                     ^
    method Collection.add(ArrayList<Integer>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Object cannot be converted to ArrayList<Integer>)
    method List.add(ArrayList<Integer>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Object cannot be converted to ArrayList<Integer>)
    method AbstractCollection.add(ArrayList<Integer>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Object cannot be converted to ArrayList<Integer>)
    method AbstractList.add(ArrayList<Integer>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Object cannot be converted to ArrayList<Integer>)
    method ArrayList.add(ArrayList<Integer>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Object cannot be converted to ArrayList<Integer>)
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
1 error
```

What am I missing here. Please shed some light on this.

Comment: The `clone()` method returns an `Object`, and so you've got to cast that clone into an ArrayList. Having said that, don't use clone at all for many very good reasons.

Comment: `arrli.add((ArrayList<Integer>) arrli1.clone());`

Comment: Please see [Why people are so afraid of using clone() (on collection and JDK classes)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597965/why-people-are-so-afraid-of-using-clone-on-collection-and-jdk-classes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comments to your question, the `clone()` method returns an Object, and since the *compiler* can see and know only this, you must (dangerously) cast the object returned to be ArrayList for the method to work:

```
arrli.add((ArrayList<Integer>) arrli1.clone());
```

Having said this, I implore you not to use `clone()` in this situation and that you read [Why people are so afraid of using clone() (on collection and JDK classes)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597965/why-people-are-so-afraid-of-using-clone-on-collection-and-jdk-classes) to see why.

If this were my code, I'd make new ArrayLists objects *within* the for loop rather than cloning existing ones. I'm not 100% sure of what you're trying to achieve here, but perhaps something similar to:

```
// list to hold other lists
List<List<Integer>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<>();

// inner list to be added to above list
List<Integer> innerList = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {  

    // if we need to create a new inner list, add old to 
    // list of lists and create new one          
    if (i != 0 && arr[i] < arr[i - 1]) {
        listOfLists.add(innerList);
        innerList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    // always add to the current inner list
    innerList.add(arr[i]);
}

// when all is done, add last inner list to list of lists
listOfLists.add(innerList);
```

This above code looks to be cleaner and safer. Also, if you're wondering why I'm using:

```
List<Integer> foo = new ArrayList<>();
```

rather than

```
ArrayList<Integer> foo = new ArrayList<>();
```

Please check out:

- [Why do some people use the List base class to instantiate a new ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17459553/why-do-some-people-use-the-list-base-class-to-instantiate-a-new-arraylist) as well as
- [What does it mean to “program to an interface”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)

Comment: Thank you so much @Hovercraft Full of Eels

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `clone()` to copy an `ArrayList`. Use the copy-constructor.

Making a deep copy of an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>` is actually very simple:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> arrli = /*...*/

// Create deep copy (no need to copy immutable Integer objects)
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> copy = new ArrayList<>(arrli.size());
for (ArrayList<Integer> sublist : arrli)
    copy.add(new ArrayList<>(sublist));
```

The code of course assumes there are no `null` sublists.

Answer (score 0):

[.clone()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#clone()) returns an Object so you must cast it into your proper type. In your case `ArrayList<Integer>`