# Creating an ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java, list, collections, arraylist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List versus ArrayList as reference type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062982/list-versus-arraylist-as-reference-type)

Whats the difference in creating an arraylist in the following ways?

```
List listA = new ArrayList(); and ArrayList alist = new ArrayList();
```

Answer (score 11):

The first assigns a list to a variable defined by its *interface*, the second defines the variable by class.

The first declaration will let you change the implementation later:

```
List listA = new LinkedList();
```

is valid, while the second would not let you change the implementation:

```
ArrayList listA = new LinkedList(); // <<<=== INVALID
```

It is worth noting that starting with Java 5 `List` is a generic type, so you should specify the type parameter to improve type safety:

```
List<ClassA> listA = new ArrayList<ClassA>();
```

Answer (score 5):

In the first case, you're hiding the implementation of the list to the code using `listA`.

This is often recommended because it (almost) ensures you can later change to another type of list without having to check dependencies in other parts of the code : code using `listA` doesn't use anything specific to the `ArrayList` class but only what is defined in the `List` interface.

Answer (score 0):

It is far discussed question :)

You should use Interfaces rather than concrete class because you can easily change implementation in any point of time

You should only use Concrete class when you want to access specific functionality of that class

Answer (score 0):

It is the same, just the reference type is different.

You should always use interfaces (like List) rather than concrete implementation like ArrayList when referring an object.