# declaring List l = new ArrayList() and ArrayList al = new ArrayList()

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List versus ArrayList as reference type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062982/list-versus-arraylist-as-reference-type)

what is difference between declaring List l = new ArrayList() and ArrayList al = new ArrayList()

Comment: Hi, while you entered the question title, a list of related questions (exactly the one on the right hand column of this page) has appeared to you. Why didn't you browse through them? At least the third and fourth already answers your concrete question.

Comment: i came to know that both represents instance of ArrayList() and also we can use methods in List interface by declaring List l = new ArrayList() . But my concern is about memory space , jvm behaviour.

Comment: Why didn't you ask that as such? Even then, why exactly do you think that a different reference type would behave differently in memory?

Comment: There is no memory consumption difference.

Answer (score 7):

When you declare `List l = new ArrayList()` l is limited to the methods provided by the interface List, while when you declare it `ArrayList al = new ArrayList()` it can use all methods and fields in an arraylist.

When you declare it `List l` then you afford yourself more flexibility as you can change out the ArrayList for something more appropriate at a later date if you want to without breaking any code.

EDIT

As Chin Boon points out you can cast `l` to an ArrayList and thereby use methods of ArrayLists on it. However *usually* if you find yourself depending on specific aspects of an ArrayList there is little point in programming to the interface (List) at all.

Comment: Not true. You can case `l` into an `ArrayList` to use methods in ArrayList.

Comment: @ChinBoon Edited to address this

Answer (score 3):

`List` is an `Interface` (Super type of ArrayList, LinkedList).
when you sat `List l = new ArrayList();`
you are creating a subclass object with super class reference, thus you can access the methods of only super class but in case of overridden methods the subclasses method would be invoked.

In your case:

```
List l = new ArrayList()
```

you will only be able to invoke methods and fields declared inside list interface.

```
ArrayList al = new ArrayList()
```

you will be able to invoke methods and fields from both the list and the arraylist.

also when you create an arraylist using approach 1

```
List l = new ArrayList();
```

later you can use the same reference to create a LinkedList like

```
l = new LinkedList();
```

which you cant using approach 2:

```
ArrayList al = new ArrayList()

al = new LinkedList()// cannot do this
```

Answer (score 0):

Declaring a variable to be of type List tells the compiler exactly what it will allow you to do with that variable. In this case, you can do all of the things defined by the List interface. Since ArrayList implements List, you can certainly assign an ArrayList to your List variable, but you will only have access to things defined in the List interface, even if ArrayList has other methods defined beyond what the List interface specifies. On the other hand, declaring the type to be ArrayList lets you do anything defined by the ArrayList class, even if it were not defined by the List type. However, if you wanted to later reassign the variable to some other type of list, you would not be able to as the compiler's type checker will require an ArrayList.