# LinkedList subList returns List instead of LinkedList?

Tags: java, list, oop, types, linked-list

I have a function `f` that gets a sublist of a `LinkedList` and passes it to `g`, which also takes a `LinkedList`:

```
public static <T> void g(LinkedList<T> l) {
}

public static <T> void f() {
    LinkedList<T> l = new LinkedList<T>();
    ...
    LinkedList<T> l2 = l.subList(i,j);
    ...
    g(l2);
}
```

But this doesn't compile, because apparently `LinkedList.subList` returns `List` instead of `LinkedList`. So I have to change it to this:

```
LinkedList<T> l2 = (LinkedList<T>)l.subList(i,j);
```

Why?

Comment: Programming to interfaces, not implementations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`subList` is defined in the `List` interface and returns a `List`. And if you check the implementation in `LinkedList`, which is actually in one of the parent classes (`AbstractList`), you will see that it does **not** return a `LinkedList` but a `SubList` and your cast will throw an exception.

Unless you use methods specific to `LinkedList`, the easiest way to fix this would be to change `g` to:

```
public static <T> void g(List<T> l) {
```

Comment: Well said mate..sublist() is from list and not from LinkedList

Comment: unfortunately, `g` requires a `LinkedList`.

Comment: You can always call `g(new LinkedList(sublist));`…

Answer (score 0):

if g() doesn't use the method of LinkedList but only the List interface is preferable to define g() as follow:

```
public static <T> void g( List<T> l ) {
}
```

and the main becomes:

```
public static <T> void f() {
    List<T> l = new LinkedList<T>();
    ...
    List<T> l2 = l.subList(i,j);
    ...
    g(l2);
}
```

For a justification, [please consult this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062982/java-oop-list-versus-arraylist-as-reference-type).

Answer (score 0):

The method `sublist` is declared in the `List` interface which is implemented by `LinkedList`. The signature of the `sublist` method in the `List` interface is:

```
 List<E> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex)
```

Thus whenever you call this method from a `LinkedList` class, the object will be of `LinkedList`, but return type of the method is `List`, thus it will be given in the form of `List`. However, you can cast the variable to `LinkedList` and use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't instantiate 'Objects' such List. List is an interface, not a concrete class.
An interface is just a set of functions that a class can implement; it doesn't make any sense to instantiate an interface.

Hope it helps.

Clemencio Morales Lucas.

Answer (score -2):

Java wants as much polymorphism as you can get, so subList returns List, and you have to cast it to what you want.

Comment: Actually, it returns a `java.util.SubList` so you can't cast it to whatever you want! `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.SubList cannot be cast to java.util.LinkedList`