# Why we should use Interface, instead of concrete types?

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

When using collections in Java, we are advised to use Interface instead of concrete types.

Like: `List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();`

But, using `ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();` will also does the same job, right?

Comment: the reason is polymorphism

Comment: I was waiting for this to explode :D

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062982/java-oop-list-versus-arraylist-as-reference-type

Comment: Just one example from real life. I had to use dynamic proxies to make one workaround (long story), but as you already know, to make dynamic proxy you have to use interface. But all references in project was, you guess, concrete type references. So I had to refactor all methods that was using concrete type with their interfaces. Not a load of work, but the lesson is, you have to use interfaces for the sake of OOP as you never know when someone/you'll have to replace concrete type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, but if you later change your mind and use a `LinkedList` You have to change much more in your code.

Answer (score 4):

That is the Polymorphism  which is the core concept of OOP.

It means ‘**a state of having many shapes**’ or ‘the capacity to take on different forms’. When applied to OOP , it describes a language’s ability to process objects of various types and classes through a single, uniform interface.

`List` is a Uniform interface and its Different implementations are like `ArrayList ,LinkedList`.....etc

Prefer to read :[What does it mean to program to a interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413543/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-a-interface)

Answer (score 2):

When you define your list as:

```
List myList = new ArrayList();
```

you can only call methods and reference members that belong to List class. If you define it as:

```
ArrayList myList = new ArrayList();
```

you'll be able to invoke ArrayList specific methods and use ArrayList specific members in addition to those inherited from List.
Nevertheless, when you call a method of a List class in the first example, which was overridden in `ArrayList`, then method from `ArrayList` will be called not the one in the List.
Also the first has the advantage that the implementation of the List can change (to a [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) for example), without affecting the rest of the code. This is will be difficult to do with an `ArrayList`, not only because you will need to change `ArrayList` to `LinkedList` everywhere, but also because you may have used `ArrayList` specific methods.

Answer (score 2):

There's a useful principle: for declared types, use the loosest (vaguest) interface possible (and `List` is 'looser' than `ArrayList`).

In practice, this means if you only need to access methods declared in `List<Object>` on your list instance (which is actually an `ArrayList`), then declare it as `List<Object>`. This means you can change your mind on the exact type of list later and you only need to change the line that actually instantiates the `ArrayList` (or `LinkedList` or whatever you choose).

This has implications for method signature too: if you were passing around an `ArrayList` instead of a `List`, and then changed your mind about it being an `ArrayList`, you have to go and edit lots of method signatures.

Please read up on [Polymorphism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html) if you'd like to know more.

Tangentially related is the Liskov Substitution Principle:

[What is the Liskov Substitution Principle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56860/what-is-the-liskov-substitution-principle)

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces or should I say base calsses are used to generalize things and problems at hand. So when you implement an interface you can always get the specific objects.

For example:
From `Animal interface` or `super class` you can always **derive** specific interfaces or calsses like `Lion`, but not the other way, becaus its true that a **Lion** is an animal but several other animals cannot be derived from **Lion**. Thats why it is advised to make things general and hence use `interfaces`. 
Same applies in your case. You can always get `ArrayList` and other implementations from a `List`.

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a class with the following method

```
public ArrayList<T> foo (ArrayList<T> someInput) {

    //Do some  operations on someInput here...

    return someOutput;

}
```

Now, what happens if you change the program so that it uses `LinkedList` objects instead of `ArrayList` objects? You will get a compiler error wherever this method is called, and you would have to go through and refactor your code so that it accepts `LinkedList` objects.

If you had programmed to an interface and used a List instead:

```
public List<T> foo (List<T> someInput) {

    //Do some operations on someInput here....

    return someOutput;

}
```

If this was the case, no refactoring would be necessary as both the `LinkedList` and `ArrayList` classes implement `List` so there would be no compiler errors. This makes it incredibly flexible. It does not matter to the method what it takes in and what it returns, as long as the objects implement the List interface. This allows you to define behaviour without exposing any of the underlying implementation.