# Entity cannot be converted to ArrayList<Entity>

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to read out the first element of an ArrayList. The problem is when i construct a return method i get an error saying 'Entity cannot be converted to ArrayList'. The return function needs to be a public ArrayList, because i'm using a foreach to return the values. Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong and what i can do to improve this?

Entity manager (public ArrayList) doesn't work.

```
public class EntityManager {

private Handler handler;
private Player player;
private ArrayList<Entity> entities;
private int counter = 0;


private Comparator<Entity> renderOrder = new Comparator<Entity>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(Entity a, Entity b) {
                if(a.getY() + a.getHeight() < b.getY() + b.getHeight())
                        return -1;
                return 1;
        }
};

public EntityManager(Handler handler, Player player){
    this.handler = handler;
    this.player = player;
    entities = new ArrayList<Entity>();
    addEntity(player);
}

public void tick(){
   Iterator<Entity> it = entities.iterator();

   while(it.hasNext()){
        Entity e = it.next();
        e.tick();
        if(!e.isActief()){
            it.remove();
            counter();
            if(counter > entities.size() + 1){
               player.eindspel = true; 
            }
        }
    }
    entities.sort(renderOrder);
}

public void render(Graphics g){
    for(Entity e : entities){
        e.render(g);
    }
    player.postRender(g);
}
public ArrayList<Entity> getEntities() {
    return entities.get(0);
}
public void counter(){
    counter++;
}
public void addEntity(Entity e){
    entities.add(e);
}

public void setHandler(Handler handler) {
    this.handler = handler;
}

public void setPlayer(Player player) {
    this.player = player;
}

public void setEntities(ArrayList<Entity> entities) {
    this.entities = entities;
}

public Handler getHandler() {
    return handler;
}
public Player getPlayer() {
    return player;
 }
}
```

The foreach i'm am using to read out the values from getEntities

```
        for(Entity e : handler.getWereld().getEntityManager().getEntities()){
        if(e.equals(this)){
            continue;
        }
        if(e.getCollisionBounds(0, 0).intersects(ar)){
            if(opslag.delete()){
                e.delete(2);                    
            }
        }
    }
```

The outcome i want is when e intersects i want to delete the entity that i get with 'return entities.get(0)', so the first entity of my entities arraylist. only that method won't work and when i use 'return entities' all of my entites get deleted, instead of only the first one.

Comment: I don't get the logic of your `getEntities()` method. That method name and the return type make it quite clear that you return several entites and still you call `return entities.get(0);` in there? How can this make sense?

Comment: I want to change the getEntities method to instead of getting all entities to just getting the first entitie in my arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

If you would generalize your external interface to use List instead of ArrayList (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062982/list-versus-arraylist-as-reference-type) why that's a good idea), you could just use [Collections.singletonList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singletonList-T-) to construct a list containing the first entity.

However, it seems pretty unintuitive to me to have a method called getEntities that just returns one entity. I still don't really get when you want to get all entities, and when just one. Maybe you can edit your question to explain your use case a little more

Answer (score 0):

you are calling delete(int ) method on an Entity

```
 e.delete(2);
```

and the method is applicable to collection I think it it were your problem comes from.